# Spring MVC IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I need some help. I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ Idea and it's my first time using that IDE. When I create a Spring MVC project the IDE doesn't generate any view or controller. What should I do?

Comment: view and controller are design methods only, you should have think of the best place and create your place in there

Comment: But I think the IDE should auto-generate those files

Comment: I've not seen IntelliJ auto-generate Controllers or Views. Not sure where you read that it could do that. There may be a plugin that could do this, but its so minor / trivial to create a Controller that I would not bother and just do this myself. Just create a class and add @Controller annotation, done.

Answer (score 1):

In intelliJ IDE, you can generate MVC pattern files in your project files by *right click on your project name in your project structure -> select "Add Framework Support"*, and then *choose "Spring MVC"* option in newly opened window. That will help you to generate needed files.

Comment: I can not find Spring MVC after I select Add Framework Support